# Launch app's activity when opening a specific link pattern

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have a little web app that sends anonymous messages as links.
I'm currently working on its Android version. The links of messages are in the pattern:

https://believe-labs.co/speak/m?somerandomkey

I want that when the receiver clicks the link of a message, and if the app is installed on the device, the browser should redirect the link to my app activity and launch it.

I tried

```
 <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="believe-labs.co/m" android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Where am I wrong and what do I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

You must use this kind of data (host & path):

```
<data 
    android:scheme="https"
    android:host="believe-labs.co"
    android:path="/speak/m" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use believe-labs.co/m in the host,you can try the below code that will work for sure because i am also using same code in my app to be open via deeplink.

```
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>

                <data
                    android:host="believe-labs.co"
                    android:scheme="https"></data>
            </intent-filter>
```